# Nexus Repository Browsing without login or as without any security

Tags: nexus

I have a very simple use case here .

Use Case/Requirement :

I would like to configure all my nexus repository very similar to what I see in https://oss.sonatype.org/#view-repositories;appfuse-releases~browseindex . That Means I just want that any organisation wide user (ldap user) should be able to **view and read** any repository listed in my Nexus Instance http://localhost:8081/nexus/ without login.

I tried lots of options in repository configuration but no luck yet . can anyone please help me run down the steps , how this can be done ?

Comment: anyone who can share their answers or provide me live chat link or support ?

Comment: To add more to this : I need to have anonymous access for all repos. Anyone who can share their answers or provide me live chat link or support ?

Answer (score 2):

{nexus_url}/nexus/#admin/security/users:anonymous

```
nx-anonymous
nx2-anonymous
nx2-repository-any-read
```

{nexus_url}/nexus/#admin/security/anonymous

```
Allow anonymous users to access the server = YES
Username = anonymous
Realm = Local Authenticating Realm
```

Answer (score -1):

Give your users these roles:

- All Repositories (Read)
- UI: Base UI Privileges
- Nexus Anonymous Role

Comment: I don't want to touch the user and it's priviledges/roles , just want that any user without login or doing anything just be able to browse and read that.