# Making Sonatype Nexus Repository publically accessible to be able to download artifacts with URL like maven central

Tags: java, maven, jboss, repository, sonatype

I am trying to make nexus repository public so that another application can use it or download it without any authentication ( with just provided URL ) just like maven central. Is there any way to do that?

e.g
I am trying to use this url to download akashh-1-javadoc.jar but it shows me login box first to download this artifact.
http://localhost:8081/repository/temp/com/akashh/1/akashh-1-javadoc.jar

[image]

Is there any way to make nexus repository public without any username or password?

Answer (score 1):

If you enable Read access for the anonymous user, this should be possible. To do so, go to Security -> Users, select "anonymous", and check that the user has the role "Repo: All repositories (read)" in the Role management box.

See the following picture how it should look like:

[image]

If you only want to have anonymous read permissions for a specific repository, you need to create a role for that specific permission and assign that role to the anonymous user.

Comment: I guess the OP is using Nexus 3.

Comment: The process should be similar (assigning the proper role to the anonymous user etc.)

Comment: Hey @dunni Thanks for the reply. But still it does not solve my problem. 
I am using Sonatype Nexus Repository ManagerOSS 3.27.0-03. I have enabled annonymous access from security > annonymous access. Still I am getting a popup window while accessing the URL.

Comment: @dunni

For your reference: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31630224/nexus-repository-browsing-without-login-or-as-without-any-security